# ReRendering with a4j:commandButton

Tags: jsf, richfaces, submit, ajax4jsf

Does the nesting of elements and multiple forms affect the capabilities of rerendering with a a4j:commandButton?

i have something like:

```
<ui:panelGrid>
    <h:form id="1">
         <a4j:commandButton rerender="1,2,3" />
    </h:form>
</ui:panelGrid>
<ui:panelGrid>
    <h:form id="2">
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="3">
    </h:form>
</ui:panelGrid>
```

Currently it does not want to reRender anything, only the action on it will get executed.
Also i have in my forms . Would that affect anything ? I use the same bean name in every keepAlive tag
I'm new to all these.

Comment: I'm not sure about the RichFaces part, but in HTML, ID's starting with a number is **illegal**.

Comment: its just for example purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by reRendering the form's parent. It's strange. Why wouldn't it rerender only the form or a element in a form?